# Image Pixel Coordinate - Pattern Recognition

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing

What is the best approach to find/read the pixel coordinates of a certain image automatically?

Currently, I created a simple webapp using a [jquery image cropper plugin](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/#overview) and php to locate the pixel coordinates of an image and cropped it using [imagemagick command](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop).

[image: my web app screenshot]

My webapp is working pretty well but still time consuming, just imagine i need to split/crop around 60k images. And in every 4 hours i can only managed to processed 300-400 images.

Comment: can't this be done on the client side?

Comment: I dont see the problem. You have a PHP method that identifies where to crop the image. Why not loop all the images with that method and crop them all?

Comment: well, this can be done on the client side, but currently (the screenshot) im the only user using this. My client just gave me the list of images and asked to split it into 2 or more depending on the number of items within a certain image. So i created that web app to make the processing easier but still time consuming.

Comment: @OptimusCrime ,that is my current approach. But the images are not all the same. The pixel coordinates changes depending on sizes, position and number of items inside of a certain image. What I want to came up with, is an algorithm somehow similar to OCR.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was what you currently had.